# Windows Installer start menu icon disappear in Windows 8.1 (Windows 8 works fine)

Tags: windows-installer, windows-8.1

We have **installer** which add an icon to start menu. It works fine on Windows 7, **Windows 8**.

But it does not add any icon to the start menu/screen on **windows 8.1**. The application **cannot be even found** in start screen search.

What have been changed between Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. How should the installer be fixed/updated?

Comment: have you tried multiple Win 8.1 machines? maybe there is a problem with this one. For testing clean VMs are recommended.

Comment: It happens on both computers with Windows 8.1 I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://vathsalas.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/create-a-tile-type-shortcut-on-windows-88-1-start-screen/), "you can either have the tile or a shortcut on the Desktop for Windows 8.1. You cannot have both."

[Let me list down what happened on each platform](http://vathsalas.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/create-a-tile-type-shortcut-on-windows-88-1-start-screen/):

- Windows 7: Shortcut on Desktop and Folder on Start Menu
- Windows 8: Shortcut as Tile on Start Screen
- Windows 8.1: Shortcut on Desktop (This is what interesting!)